# Waiting for flash player to connect to debugger

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, flexbuilder

Using Flex Builder 3 :
I have been getting this problem in every single debug launch for past few hours.
I used to get this earlier too, but once in a while, not with every debug launch.
I found out that flex debugger uses a certain 7935 port but I can't figure out
how to change it?

Comment: The whole debug/profile launch part of FlexBuilder is a complete let down and constantly prone to failure. Sadly, the (Adobe) alternatives for ActionScript authoring are somewhat worse. I'm considering a wholesale move to FlashDevelop.

Comment: This might solve your problem
http://blog.air4android.com/?p=59 HTH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember getting this problem a few times.  It might have to do with the Flex Profiler (I used to accidentally click that every now and then trying to launch the debugger).

If you start the Profiler and stop it too fast, it will add something to a file in your home directory that it shouldn't.

Check out `/path/to/home/mm.cfg` on your operating system (on mac, you can open it in textmate with `mate ~/mm.cfg`).  The `mm.cfg` file stores some information about debugging in Flex

Then in that file, make sure this is the only content:

```
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1
```

If there's an extra line (can't remember/find it, something like

```
PreloadSwf=/Users/[username]/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.adobe.flash.profiler/ProfilerAgent.swf?host=localhost&port=9999
```

), delete it.

Let me know if that fixes it.

Lance

Comment: It works.
I have deleted the mm.cfg file.
In fact I had manually created this file in order to make the Profiler work with the "PreloadSwf" command. Though the Profiler didn't work even after that :-)

Comment: So,  basically I just deleted this file, since the Profiler wasn't working anyway.

Comment: cool :). I don't know if you should delete the file though, you might want to keep it there with those two lines in there, who knows what'll happen. cheers!

Comment: The mm.cfg file might also be located in /Library/Application Support/Macromedia on Mac OS X

Answer (score 3):

Also just make sure you're not using Chrome. Flash Player debugger (at the time of writing this) does not work in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: right click on a SWF, select "Open with...", choose "Other...", select the Debug player and check the "Always Open With" checkbox.
Mac OSX / FlashBuilder4

Answer (score 2):

Right click your launched flash application, either in the browser or standalone flash player and click on debugger if enabled and change the radio button from localhost to other machine and enter the ip 127.0.0.1 and you are free to debug. I guess the problem maybe from your host file.

Comment: what do you mean "click on debugger" - how do I get there?

Comment: If you are running the Debugger version of Flash, right clicking wil bring up a menu with the Debugger option. Otherwise change your settings or install the relevant debugger version http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Answer (score 2):

Changing the browser from default (chrome) to IE worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Similar to danjp - This started happening to me after a Flash Player automatic update. I simply reinstalled the debug flash players from the [Adobe Flash Player download page](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a swf file with the proper name in your bin-debug directory and that name matches the swf name specified in index.template.html file for the project.

I had replaced index.template.html file by mistake with a similar one from another project. When I tried to debug, I got this "Waiting for flash player to connect to debugger…" status till it timed out.

Answer (score 0):

To me the problem was that internet explorer opened and showed a certification problem, if i didn´t continue this the debugger would show this error. If i continued on ie, no problem happens.